# MongoDB - update data in array of objects within object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document in mongoDB structured like that

```
_id: ObjectId("generatedByMongo"),
name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
last: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
grades: [{
    grade: {
       _id: ObjectId(""),
       grade: Number,
       date: date 
    } 

}]
```

And to server I send array of objects containing 3 fields

```
[
 {studentId}, {gradeId}, {newGrade}
]
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is I want to find in within that user collection `grade` with given `gradeId` and update it's value to `newGrade`**. As far as I tried to do that I have done this

```
router.patch('/students/updateGrade',async(req,res) => {
        const studentId = req.body.updateGradeArray[0].studentId;
        const gradeId = req.body.updateGradeArray[0].gradeId;
        const newGrade = req.body.updateGradeArray[0].newGrade;
        try {
            const student = await Student.find({_id: studentId})
                                         .select({'grades': {$elemMatch: {_id: gradeId}}});

        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You have to use the update method (you are using the find method). Find can only read, and update can find the document and change the values.

Comment: Do you intend to update only the grade.grade(the number value)? or the entire grade object?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for quick response. My goal is to update grades.grade(gradeId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to update just grade.grade(the number value), try this:

```
Student.updateOne(
  // Find a document with _id matching the studentId
  { "_id": studentId },
  // Update the student grade
  { $set: { "grades.$[selectedGrade].grade": newGrade } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "selectedGrade._id": gradeId }] },
)
```

**Why this should work:**
Since you are trying to update a student document, you should be using one of MongoDB update methods not find. In the query above, I'm using the [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) method. Inside the updateOne, I am using a combination of [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) and [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) update operators to update the student grade.

I hope this helps✌